# How to rename the sites directory in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, central-administration, administration, site

I have to rename the **/Sites** directory to **/Tasks**.

Eg. **http://pc18:1818/sites/task1** to **http://pc18:1818/tasks/task1**.

Is this Possible? How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this via Powershell by using the following script to rename sub-site / site collection

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://pc18:1818/sites/task1 
$uri = New-Object System.Uri("http://pc18:1818/tasks/task1") 
$site.Rename($uri)
```

Then force the Content Database to refresh its site map with this:

```
((Get-SPSite http://pc18:1818/tasks/task1).contentdatabase).RefreshSitesInConfigurationDatabase
```

Then perform `IISRESET`

For more details check the detailed story at [How to Rename SharePoint 2013 Site Collections Without Prayer or Sobbing](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=573)

Comment: I don't want to rename the site collection!
I want to rename the Sites directory.
Is it possible with the above solution? I'll check it soon!

Comment: yes , it's also working with subsite , try to check it in a test subsite and tell me result :) then apply it to real subsite